# How to implement Paypal Profile sharing with Braintree?

Tags: paypal, braintree

Using Paypal-Mobile-iOS-SDK > PayPalProfileSharingViewController.

we was share paypal account profile for purpose of paypal murchant accounts manage from server side.

but now Paypal-Mobilei-OS-SDK deprecated. we can intergrate paypal using Braintree.
but i am not getting good way to perform paypal profile sharing with Braintree sdk.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Unfortunately, the PayPal profile sharing feature is not part of the Braintree SDK and is not supported by our SDK.

Comment: @JacqueD perfact thanks. Yes, Braintree SDK not supported PayPal profile sharing.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get profile share without the deprecated library?

Comment: @CecilRodriguez no other way to get PayPal profile.

Comment: @CecilRodriguez you can use your custom UI to take PayPal email in that UI also add confirmation PayPal email.

Comment: I just integrated the deprecated library into the project